# iOS : Email ID as well as phone number evaluation in one text field

Tags: ios, validation, uitextfielddelegate

User can enter email id OR phone in one text field. If the user number enters email id, email is validated. If the user enters phone, phone number is validated. Validation should be done in one text field only. I am aware of email id and phone number validation and the method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

How to detect if the user enters email id or phone and then validate accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

If the `NSString` object from `textfield` contains character **@** then it is an email otherwise it is not. In addition we can also check if the string containd=s ten characters and all are digits for phone validation.

You can use the below code to find the **@** character.

```
  NSString *str = self.textField.text;
  NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"@"];
  if (range.location != NSNotFound)
  {
    // it is an email
  }
  else if(str.length == 10 && [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"]].location != NSNotFound) {
    // it is a phone
  }
  else{
    // it is neither of the two
  }
```

Comment: You can club that code in the if-clause. There is no point to start another if condition.

Answer (score 1):

The user can enter both but you don´t know what he´s actually trying to enter.

I suggest you apply both validations. If one of them is successful, you know what he has entered and you can proceed.

Edit: Reading other answers I don´t think checking the "@" char is a good idea since the user could have mistakenly not entered that character (ie pressed number 2), and you are going to apply the wrong validation

Comment: I think it can't be done. I have to make two separate text fields only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write two validators and check if one of them finishes with success.

```
- (BOOL) isTextValid: (NSString *) text
{
    return [self isPhoneNumberValid: text] || [self isEmailValid: text];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check a if...else condition.

If entered word has @ character, go for email id validation
else go for phone validation.

Answer (score 0):

Validation of UITextfield text use this method

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField  because

shouldChangeCharactersInRange method every time it is call whenever user type the keyboard

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

  if(textField.tag = 1){

  if([self isValidPhoneNumber]||[self isValidEmail]){

  return success ;

  }else{

  return fails ;
  }

}

}

Answer (score 0):

All of you got my question wrong it seems.
I finally solved it like this. I had to validate both (email id && phone number) in emailIdTextField

```
NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
     NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];

     NSString *phoneRegex = @"^((\\+)|(00))[0-9]{6,14}$";
     NSPredicate *phoneTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex];

    if([emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.emailTextField.text] == NO && [phoneTest evaluateWithObject:self.emailTextField.text] == NO)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can't login" message:@"Please enter a valid email id / phone no. (abc@xyz.com OR +11234567890)" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alertView show];

    }

    else
    {
        //login successful

    }
```